# How to draw custom shapes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painter

I'm trying to draw a custom shape like this in my app:

[image]

Tried to draw using custom painter, but haven't figured out how to get this sort of shape. It's really just a container with a custom border I think, but not sure even where to start. It's just the shape I'm interested in, not the content.

Or if someone knows how to draw a rounded rectangle with a thinner bottom section, then that would really help me to work out the rest.

Also, does anyone here know how to draw a rounded rectangle that is thinner in the middle, like the shape behind the purple one in the example I've given?

Any help is grately appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this tools

[this is the link](https://flutter-shapemaker.web.app/)

download it for your windows and draw your shape and generate the code..

here is the tutorial on how to use the tools

[the tutorial on how to use it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4)

Comment: Thank you so much, looks like a great tool, I should be able to do this now.

Comment: okay... i use it yesterday... after posting to stack no response even vote down my question

Comment: CustomePaint is a better solution.

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga how can we make multiple shapes in one canvas?

Comment: @MuhammadUmairSaqib open a question base on this, so if i am free, i will be able to answer if is in my capability